# Prove or disprove hypotheses

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, dataset

[removed, apparently its duplicated question..]

Comment: Did you just ask the same question a few days ago & delete it? Please don't re-ask the same question; sometimes it takes a while before an answer appears. Spamming the site does not help & is not appreciated.

Comment: No I did not? this is the first time I use this page :P

Comment: Hmmm, where did this question come from then? Is this from a course or textbook? There was a very similar question a couple of days ago.

Comment: It's from a course